# Combining a statement and function

Tags: jquery

I need to combine the following statement:

```
if($('#checkbox-h-2a').is(':checked')) { 
            $('.sptext').text(sptext);
            $('.SPNum').html(SPval);
        }
```

With the following function:

```
$("select[name='hospital']").change(function () {
    SPval = $("option:selected", this).data("data").SPval;
    $('.SPNum').html(SPval);

});
```

I need the values in the 'if" conditional to be defined when BOTH the hospital select menu changes AND checkbox-h-2a has been checked. Im just not sure how to combine the two!

Comment: who provides the value for `sptext`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it on an "event" ... an event is a user action. Like on click, hover, change.

So the if statement will only run once on page load or ready if you don't have it inside an event function.

So this is the correct way to do it.

```
$("select[name='hospital']").change(function () {
    SPval = $("option:selected", this).data("data").SPval;
    $('.SPNum').html(SPval);

    if($('#checkbox-h-2a').is(':checked')) { 
            $('.sptext').text(sptext);
            $('.SPNum').html(SPval);
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("select[name='hospital'], #checkbox-h-2a").change(function () {
    var SPval = $("select[name='hospital'] option:selected").data("data").SPval;
    $('.SPNum').html(SPval);
    if ($('#checkbox-h-2a').is(':checked')) {
        //need to get the value for sptext
        $('.sptext').text(sptext);
    }
});
```